# Electron using EJS

Tags: node.js, electron, ejs

In my Electron app, I want to open my .ejs view when I click the button.

So I try to implement the same logic as nodejs an did this ;

```
   document.getElementById('goto-exitW-button').addEventListener('click', () => {
   window.location="/whouseExit";
   });
```

and here is the code snippet from **main.js** ;

```
appExpress.get("/whouseExit",(req,res) => {

 var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;
 var Request = require('tedious').Request;

  var config = {
    server: 'localhost',
    authentication: {
      type: 'default',
      options: {
        userName: 'sa',
        password: '42345243',
      },
    },
    options: {
      encrypt: false,
      database: 'cusst',
    },
  };

  const connection = new Connection(config);

  connection.connect((err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Connection Failed');
      throw err;
    }

    executeStatement()
      .then((myRows) => {
        
        res.render('whouseExitejs.ejs', { myRows });

      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  });


  function executeStatement() {     // database stuff 
    ....
  }

});
```

However, when I click the button it does not work and complain " Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/whouseExit "

What am I doing wrong ?

( **whouseExitejs.ejs is under views folder and I included appExpress.set('view engine', 'ejs');** )

Comment: If you're using a `<button>` for a page navigation, _don't use a button_, use the navigation element. This is literally what `<a>` is for, just make it look like a button with CSS =)

Comment: do you think, it complains bcs of this?

Comment: I think you're making things needlessly complicated and using an `<a href="...">` means there is no javascript to go wrong. Links "just work(tm)" because that's their sole purpose in life.